# memcpy() instruction in ARM EABI compiler explanation

Tags: c, arm, memcpy, toolchain, eabi

I am using the memcpy() function using the ARM EABI compiler. As I see in the  file, the function is defined as

```
extern _ARMABI void *memcpy(void * __restrict /*s1*/,
                    const void * __restrict /*s2*/, size_t /*n*/)
                    __attribute__((__nonnull__(1,2)));
   /*
    * copies n characters from the object pointed to by s2 into the object
    * pointed to by s1. If copying takes place between objects that overlap,
    * the behaviour is undefined.
    * Returns: the value of s1.
    */
```

Please forgive my ignorance;as I am not much familiar with C and pointers in general.Could someone please detail me what does it mean by const void * and does those syntaxes (like __attribute etc.) need to be maintained while calling the function?

Thanks!

My implementation:

```
char mycharacter;
mycharacter = ROM_UARTCharGetNonBlocking(UART0_BASE);
memcpy(SRAM_BASE, mycharacter, size_t (mycharacter);
```

Comment: Your code should not compile...

Comment: See _just about any introductory C reference ever written_ for an explanation of C types (and just ignore the nonstandard compiler attributes)

Comment: Why are you passing `memcpy` a *character* for its second parameter?! It needs to know what memory to copy from and to. And for what possible reason would you cast the character to a `size_t`?! (It sounds like you just have no idea how to use `memcpy` at all.)

Comment: Ok...so how should I do that since i do not have the memory address of mycharacter?

Comment: The & operator lets you take the reference of a variable. Honestly if you have questions about the C language and syntax you should read up on that before asking questions on SO.

Comment: ^ and by reference I really meant pointer or address

Comment: @Kashif you will need to explain what you are trying to do , it's not clear from your code

Comment: @MattMcNabb: i am trying to write received values over UART to SRAM for a stellaris device. so the rxed values are put in say mycharacter which will then transfer it to SRAM.

Comment: `mycharacter` is a `char` - it can only hold one character at a time. Is this code intended to be called once for each character?    NB. what does this function return if no characters are available?

Comment: this code is to be called everytime a character is available over the UART. so say a stream of 16 bytes is written over UART then these 16 bytes should be copied to the SRAM. this is what I am trying to do basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of having a standard library is that you don't have to understand the implementation to use the function.

Comment: interesting...got ur point..however,as I said I am interested in using this function but getting errors...i will add the code which I am trying to use...

Comment: It seems like you have no idea how to use `memcpy` and should start by reading as much documentation on that function as you can find until you understand it.

Comment: precisely yes, thats why I requested an explanation of the function...do you have any helpful links on this?

Comment: You can start with [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm).

Comment: got it...i have made some progress now but stuck with 2 errors:  uart_echo.c(95): error:  #167: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *restrict"

Comment: Why are you passing an `int` to `memcpy`? It wants addresses of chunks of memory.